# <div> Parent is not affecting <div> child?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a periodic table, and I came across a problem:

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  font-size: 5px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
div {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.row1 {
  margin-left: 92px;
  background-color: #FFCC33;
}
#lithium {
  margin-top: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
  <div id="lithium">Li
    <p>Lithium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sodium">Na
    <p>Sodium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="potassium">K
    <p>Potassium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rubidium">Rb
    <p>Rubidium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="cesium">Cs
    <p>Cesium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="francium">Fr
    <p>Francium</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case i want to change all div elements that are child to class 'row1' to #FFCC33. It works well if i just put all div's names(i.e. #lithium, #sodium,...{background-color: SOMECOLOR;}, but when i put class name(i.e. row1), it just affects the first child(in this case, its lithium). I have tried changing id to class and vice-versa to no avail. Is this supposed to even work or am I doing everything wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.row1 > div {
  margin-left: 92px;
  background-color: #FFCC33;
}
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/c6p77jsv/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make sure that all `<div>` children of `.row1` have a background color of `FFCC33`, try a selector like this:

```
.row1 > div {
    background-color: #FFCC33;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `height:70px` in `div`

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  font-size: 5px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
div {
  width: 70px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.row1 {
  margin-left: 92px;
  background-color: #FFCC33;
}
#lithium {
  margin-top: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
  <div id="lithium">Li
    <p>Lithium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sodium">Na
    <p>Sodium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="potassium">K
    <p>Potassium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rubidium">Rb
    <p>Rubidium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="cesium">Cs
    <p>Cesium</p>
  </div>
  <div id="francium">Fr
    <p>Francium</p>
  </div>
</div>
```